# Ada: objects with variable-sized array attribute

Tags: generics, ada, dynamic-arrays

I want to create a tagged type inside a package that describes a 2D discrete space, with a size determined in running time.
(context : implementation of a [game of life](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conway%27s_Game_of_Life))

First way I found was genericity :

```
generic
    Size : Natural;
package Worlds is
    type World_Type is tagged private;
    type World is access World_Type'Class;
    subtype Coordinate is Positive range 1..Size;
private
    type World_Array is array (Coordinate, Coordinate) of Boolean;
    type World_Type is tagged record
            Content : World_Array;
    end record;
end Worlds;
```

But, when implementing a visitor for worlds, genericity become a big problem :

```
with Worlds;

package World_Visitors is
    type World_Visitor_Type is tagged private;
    type World_Visitor is access World_Visitor_Type'Class;

    procedure Visite(v : World_Visitor_Type;
                     w : in out Worlds.World); -- ERROR: invalid prefix in selected component "Worlds"
private
    type World_Visitor_Type is tagged null record;
end World_Visitors;
```

GNAT can't compile that, because Worlds is a generic package. 
Then, because I don't want to write a Visitor for each possible world size, I try the C++ way : declare the size as attribute in the tagged type.

```
package Worlds is
    type World_Type is tagged private;
    type World is access World_Type'Class;
    subtype Coordinate is Positive range <>;

    function Init(Size : Natural) return World; -- initialize Content attribute as an array of length (Size*Size)
private
    type World_Array is array (Coordinate, Coordinate) of Boolean;
    type World_Type is tagged record
            Content : World_Array;
            Size    : Natural;
    end record;
end Worlds;
```

And, expectedly, this doesn't work, because World_Array needs an explicit range for Coordinates.
In fact, I have no idea how to create a running-time-choosen sized array in a tagged type. 
I got some ideas from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13735274/dynamic-array-size-determined-at-runtime-in-ada), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22768834/ada-packing-record-with-variable-sized-array), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732027/returning-a-variable-sized-matrix-from-a-function-in-ada) or [here](http://www.adahome.com/Ammo/cpp2ada.html#4.3), but nothing seems to make sense in this case.

How does Ada implement objects with variable-sized array attribute?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The normal Ada way to address this problem is to use a *discriminant* (see [ARM 3.7](http://www.ada-auth.org/standards/12rm/html/RM-3-7.html)).

In your case, this would look something like

```ada
package Worlds is
   type World_Type (Size : Natural) is tagged private;
   type World is access World_Type’Class;          -- ‘’ to fix SO colour bug
private
   type World_Array is array (Positive range <>, Positive range <>) of Boolean;
   type World_Type (Size : Natural) is tagged record
      Content : World_Array (1 .. Size, 1 .. Size);
   end record;
end Worlds;
```

in which `World_Array` is an example of an *unconstrained array type* ([ARM 3.6](http://www.ada-auth.org/standards/12rm/html/RM-3-6.html)). You’d create a new world by code like

```ada
W : Worlds.World := new Worlds.World_Type (Size => 100);
```

Note that you can’t change the `Size` after the object has been created.

I left out `Coordinate`; and you may get away without `Init`, especially if you provide an initializer for `Content`:

```ada
      Content : World_Array (1 .. Size, 1 .. Size) :=
        (others => (others => False));
```

*Edited 26.iii.15: Code was creating an array of size `Size + 1` x `Size + 1`.*

Comment: Is there a way to allow the reallocation of Content (for reach a bigger size, by example), or its necessary to operate an explicite copy of a World in a new one ?

Comment: With this scheme you can’t reallocate, you can only copy. You could make the `Content` be an *access* to a `World_Array`, in which case you wouldn’t need the discriminant, but you would need your `Init`; that would allow reallocation. You’d have to do the memory management, which would ideally be done by deriving `World_Type` from `Ada.Finalization.Controlled` (or `Limited_Controlled`) and implementing `Finalize`.

Answer (score 4):

```ada
procedure Visite(v : World_Visitor_Type;
                     w : in out Worlds.World); -- ERROR: invalid prefix in selected component "Worlds"
```

This won't ever work -- this is because Worlds is a generic package, type-wise there's no such actual-thing as Worlds.World. (This is to say that the type of parameter `w` can never match an instantiation.)

One way to solve this is to make `World_Visitors` generic with Worlds as a parameter. Like so:

```ada
   generic
      X : Positive;
   package temp is
      subtype Index is Integer range 1..X;
   end temp;

   generic
      with package K is new temp(<>);
   package temp_dependant is
      -- Note that parameter I now CAN depend on temp, via formal parameter K.
      function J( I: K.Index ) return Boolean is (True);
   end temp_dependant;
```

Another way would be to move the visitor into the Worlds package.
Yet another would be to make the visitor's package a child of Worlds.

Comment: Or make it a child package.